# Nice Labels with X in To Field of Compose Message?

Tags: javascript

In Facebook's Compose Message, each name that appears in the TO field uses a nice LABEL with an X.  Click on the X, and you remove name from the To sender field.  I see this same feature again in other web2.0 social networking apps.

Are there open source tools that let me make those nice X LABELS after you click on the autocomplete list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a reasonably facebook-like [jQuery plugin](http://wharsojo.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/jquery-facebook-autocomplete/) to do this.

Comment: thank you, i also found a scriptaculous equivalent for it too